# Turbo Cannot read property of Undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making an audio streaming site following this tutorial (https://www.turbo360.co/tutorial/audio-streaming-app) that allows users to upload music files to their page. However, when a user first signs in, with no files uploaded, I get this error: 
app.js:67 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
Anyone know why I can't get it to work?
Here is my code:

```
var renderTracks = function(){
    if (currentUser == null)
        return

    var tracksList = ''
        currentUser.tracks.forEach(function(track, i){
            tracksList += '<tr><td style="width:130px"><a 
            target="_blank" href="' + track.url + '"><img 
            src="/dist/images/playbutton.png" alt="..." /></a></td>'
            tracksList += '<td><h5><a target="_blank" href="' + 
            track.url + '">' + track.name + '</a></h5><p>Uploaded: ' 
            + track.timestamp + '</p></td>'
            tracksList += '<td><h4 class="price">$40</h4></td></tr>'
        })

    $('#tracks-table').html(tracksList)
}
```

I tried creating an if statement that creates a track array before a user is logged in, but it didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: forEach requires the array to work, you should create an empty array in the currentUser object if you don't have any tracks to get.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough of the context of the rest of your application, but it sounds like a currentUser exists and you get to your next block, but the tracks key does not exist.  What I would suggest when you come up on these types of situations, just placing a console.log statement and see what you get; i.e:

var renderTracks = function(){
    if (currentUser == null)
        return

```
var tracksList = ''

    console.log(JSON.stringify(currentUser))

    currentUser.tracks.forEach(function(track, i){
        tracksList += '<tr><td style="width:130px"><a 
        target="_blank" href="' + track.url + '"><img 
        src="/dist/images/playbutton.png" alt="..." /></a></td>'
        tracksList += '<td><h5><a target="_blank" href="' + 
        track.url + '">' + track.name + '</a></h5><p>Uploaded: ' 
        + track.timestamp + '</p></td>'
        tracksList += '<td><h4 class="price">$40</h4></td></tr>'
    })

$('#tracks-table').html(tracksList)
```

}